# Aspect Oriented / Object Oriented Programming?

Tags: oop, aop

What is Aspect Oriented Programming? Can Aspect Oriented Programming (ASP) replace Object Oriented Programming (OOP)? Please reply with solid arguments.

Comment: check this bro -> http://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-aop-and-vs-oop/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In computing, aspect-oriented programming (AOP) is a programming paradigm that aims to increase modularity by allowing the separation of cross-cutting concerns. AOP forms a basis for aspect-oriented software development. AOP includes programming methods and tools that support the modularization of concerns at the level of the source code. Aspect-oriented programming entails breaking down program logic into distinct parts (so-called concerns, cohesive areas of functionality). Nearly all programming paradigms support some level of grouping and encapsulation of concerns into separate, independent entities by providing abstractions (e.g., functions, procedures, modules, classes, methods) that can be used for implementing, abstracting and composing these concerns. Some concerns "cut across" multiple abstractions in a program, and defy these forms of implementation. These concerns are called **cross-cutting concerns**.

*Logging* exemplifies a crosscutting concern because a logging strategy necessarily affects every logged part of the system. *Logging thereby crosscuts all logged classes and methods.*

---

First of all AOP will not replace OOP. AOP extends OOP.

One shouldn't see AOP as a replacement of OOP, more as an nice add-on, that makes our code more clean, loosely-coupled and focused on the business logic. So by applying AOP you will get two major benefits:

1) The logic for each concern is now in one place, as opposed to being scattered all over the code base.

2) Classes are cleaner since they only contain code for their primary concern (or core functionality) and secondary concerns have been moved to aspects.